# Orden personalizado de lista en Xamarin (List<string>)

Tags: c#, android, array, lista, xamarin

Buen día,

Tengo una lista de tipo `List<string>` en Xamarin:

```
List<string> Usuarios = new List<string>();
```

La lista se carga segun el resultado de la busqueda; si busco por ejemplo: ****"Pedro"**** me muestra todos los usuarios que llevan la palabra Pedro.
Ejemplo:

-Andrés Pedro López

-Pedro Luis Sánchez

-San Pedro Hernández

-Enrique Pedro Matamoros

Eso funciona bien, al final la ordeno usando:

```
Usuarios.Sort();
```

El problema es que son listas largas y necesito poder ordenarlo iniciando del que inicie con **"Pedro"**, o al menos con la letra "**P**" (en este caso), para que los primeros resultados sean los mas relevantes y no sea de la A - Z.

Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Podrias utilizar `linq` para ordenar y filtrar la lista

```
var query = Usuarios.Where(u=> u.Contains(filtro)).OrderBy(u=> u).ToList();
```

[Enumerable.OrderBy()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netcore-3.1)

O si prefieres la notacion linq

```
var query = (from u in Usuarios
             where u.Contains(filtro)
             orderby u
             select u).ToList();
```

[Sorting Operators: OrderBy & OrderByDescending](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/linq-sorting-operators-orderby-orderbydescending)